# Emulator For Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android-emulator

Is there an emulator for the new Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Answer (score 2):

FOUND IT!!!

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9500&listReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Finnovator.samsungmobile.com%3A80%2Fdown%2Fcnts%2FtoolSDK.list.do%3FplatformId%3D1%26indexType%3D1%26indexDirection%3D1%26sortType%3D0%26cateId%3D1025%26codeType%3DAll%26searchText%3D%26curPage%3D2%26listLines%3D%26formData%3Dnumber1%26nacode%3D&nacode=

Googled yesterday with no luck but today I got it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse you can get the official Samsung Galaxy Tab emulator from the Android SDK manager by expanding Android 2.2 (API 8). There you will see GALAXY Tab by Samsung Electronics. Note that *SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8* is a prerequisite for the emulator.

You can find the detailed information [here](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9445)